# how to pass xml to xmllint in a variable instead of a file?

Tags: shell

i want to do this

```
xmllint --xpath "//filestodelete[filename = somename]/text()" #filestodelete#
```

and filestodelete is a BPEL variable of type XML

but it does not work

how to do this>??

Comment: You have your XML document in a shell variable?

Comment: I'm assuming, in my answer, that BPEL variables are exposed as shell variables. Should this not be true, you have a BPEL question, not just a shell question, and it needs to be tagged appropriately.

Comment: yes i am working with a framework that allows using BPEL variables in shell ....it means that the filestodelete variable is a BPEL variable of type xml. but it is not a file on the system.

Comment: If you want to talk about BPEL variables, you need to tag your question bpel. If your variables are shell variables, then you don't need to tell us anything about BPEL at all. Now, the third option is that you're doing string substitution to generate your shell scripts -- which would leave me... skeptical... about the wisdom of the people who developed your BPEL engine -- but in that case the heredoc approach will work fine, assuming that you use a sigil that can't exist within the variable content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you've put your query text in a shell variable named `query` (to make my examples terser) --

With bash, you can use a herestring:

```
xmllint --xpath "$query" - <<<"$filestodelete"
```

With POSIX sh, you need to use a heredoc:

```
xmllint --xpath "$query" - <<EOF
$filestodelete
EOF
```

By the way -- since not all versions of `xmllint` support `--xpath`, you'd have better compatibility across releases if you used [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) instead, which has supported the following from its initial creation:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "$query" -v . <<<"$filestodelete"
```

Comment: so does this work with xml that is stored in a variable rather than physically on a local unix system?

Comment: `$filestodelete` is expected to be your variable with the XML here, not a filename -- which is to say, yes, of course it does.

Comment: maybe  i put it wrong, filestodelete is a document of type xsd...and it it a workfow variable, not a physical file on the drive

Comment: I don't expect it to be a file on the drive. This answer requires it to be a shell variable. If you don't know how to put a workflow variable in a shell variable, then you have a BPEL question, not a shell question.

Comment: That said -- an XSD is a schema definition; it describes the format in which XML files store data, it doesn't store data itself. So if you have an XSD file, not an XML file, trying to retrieve data from it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sakal If this is the answer to your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!