# WGET - Fetch multiple XPaths from same source using only one HTTP request

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xpath, wget

I need to parse an HTML table and its "header". Both of these are included in the same URL. This is what I have up to this point:

```
#!/bin/bash

name_query="html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()"

# Use xargs to TRIM result.
header=$(wget -O - "https://example.com/section-1/name-1/financial-data/" |
    xmllint --html --xpath "$name_query" - 2>/dev/null |
    xargs)

wget -O - "https://example.com/section-1/name-1/financial-data/" |
    xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="financial-data"]/div/table/tbody' - 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/tbody/tr" --type elem -n td -v "$header" >> /Applications/parser/output.txt
```

This makes two requests:

1. Fetch the name and pass it to variable `$header`
2. Get the table and append a subnode `<td>$header</td>`

Hence, this writes the following to my **output.txt** file:

```
<tbody>

                    <tr class="text-right">
                      <td class="text-left">Sep 08, 2017</td>
                      <td>4605.16</td>     
                      <td>4661.00</td>
                      <td>4075.18</td>
                      <td>4228.75</td>
                      <td>2,700,890,000</td>
                      <td>76,220,200,000</td>
                      <td>Name 1</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="text-right">
                      <td class="text-left">Sep 07, 2017</td>
                      <td>4589.14</td>     
                      <td>4655.04</td>
                      <td>4491.33</td>
                      <td>4599.88</td>
                      <td>1,844,620,000</td>
                      <td>75,945,000,000</td>
                      <td>Name 1</td>
                    </tr>
...
</tbody>
```

It's relatively slow and somehow inefficient because it actually makes the same request twice. I believe this can be done through one request only.

I am looking for something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

name_query="html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()"

content=$(wget -O - "https://example.com/section-1/name-1/financial-data/")

# Use xargs to TRIM result.
header=$($content | xmllint --html --xpath "$name_query" - 2>/dev/null | xargs)

$content | 
    xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="financial-data"]/div/table/tbody' - 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/tbody/tr" --type elem -n td -v "$header" >> /Applications/parser/output.txt
```

This does not work and produces the following error:

```
./test: line 8: <!DOCTYPE: command not found
./test: line 10: <!DOCTYPE: command not found
-:1.1: Document is empty
```

And yes indeed, the output file is empty. I can't figure out why.

---

**ALTERNATIVE ANSWER**

Another way to approach this would be using a [herestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414861/how-to-pass-xml-to-xmllint-in-a-variable-instead-of-a-file):

```
#!/bin/bash

title_query="html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()"

content=$(wget -O - "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/")

# Use xargs to TRIM result.
header=$(xmllint --html --xpath "$title_query" - <<<"$content" 2>/dev/null | xargs)

xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@id="financial-data"]/div/table/tbody' - <<<"$content" 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/tbody/tr" --type elem -n td -v "$header" >> /Applications/parser/output.txt
```

This `<<<"$content"` also worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell bash what are you doing with the $content var.

And bash thinks that what you have in $content is the command

Use

```
echo $content | ....
```

Comment: Yes! @Fabricio Works like a charm. Thank you :)